# Изменения цвета шапки (title) DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, customview, dialogfragment

Пытаюсь программно изменить цвет title диалога. Делаю так:

```
TextView title = (TextView)getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
title.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);
```

Вместо зеленого цвета появляется фиолетовый. Такое ощущения, что зеленый смешивается с каким-то цветом и получается не тот, что мне нужен.

Как мне установить цвет, который я передаю в `setBackgroundColor()`?

Comment: Вот так пробовали? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25662113/4829111

Comment: пробовал, изменяется цвет полоски под титулом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ оказался рядом.
Вместо

```
title.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);
```

использовать

```
title.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
int titleLayoutId = dialog.getContext().getResources().
getIdentifier("topPanel", "id", "android"); 

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(titleLayoutId);
if (layout != null) {
    layout.setBackgroundColor(yourColor);
}
```

Comment: Цвет остается прозрачным. `layout == null`